# acessing Jquery object variable inside object literal function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, object-literal

I'm not able to understand why can't I check the .change() method of a jquery object stored in a variable. Is this a syntax error? Did I lost the context?

Here's my code:

```
var MyObj = {

    //declaration
    reference : $('#reference'),
    observeReference : function() {

        //The following line is not tracking the .change() method. 
        //Not sure why... And I didn't any get console error!
        this.reference.change(function() {
            var opt = $('#reference option:selected').text();

            if (opt === 'other' || opt === 'reference') {
                $('#input_other').fadeIn();
            } else{
                $('#input_other').fadeOut();
                $('#input_other_bx').val('');
            };
        }.bind(this));      
    },
    init: function() {
        this.observeReference();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
     MyObj.init();
});
```

Comment: Chances are your `id="reference"` element doesn't exist when your `MyObj` is declared. There's also no point asking us *"is this a syntax error"*; you can simply check your developer tools console.

Comment: @Phil Yes, that should be the problem, setting the property in the `init` scope should solve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Phil, tx for your attention. Actually as I said on the code comments, "...I didn't any get console error!". But still the code wasn't running, that's why I asked about syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$('#reference')` execute before document ready, it will get a jquery object which `length = 0`.

init method will execute after document ready, so assign reference in init method .

```
var MyObj = {

//declaration
reference : null,
...

init: function() {
    this.reference = $('#reference');
    this.observeReference();
}
```